# best way to receive a list of objects from list of KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, key-value

I have a list of KeyValuePairs and I want to filter it based on the key value so eventually I will get a list of values which is filtered (meaning - will not contain all the values that were in the original list).

I guess maybe the best way is some form of Lambda expression but I am not sure how to achieve it.
Thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var values = list.Where(x => x.Key == "whatever").Select(x => x.Value);
```

This will give you a filtered list of the values only.
Obviously you can change the way you filter your keys.

Comment: thanks, actually did it with a full linq statement - something like this:

Comment: Code is missing `.First()`. Must be `var values = list.Where(x => x.Key == "whatever").Select(x => x.Value).First();`. otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(x => x.Key == "Key");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for some combination of [LINQ extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (which depends on what you're exactly trying to do).

For example if I had a List of fruits to their colors and wanted to get a collection of which fruits are red, I would do something like:

```
var fruits = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>() { 
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Apple", "Green"),
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Orange", "Orange"), 
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Strawberry", "Red"), 
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Cherry", "Red") 
        };

var redFruits = fruits.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == "Red").Select(kvp => kvp.Key);

// this would result in a IEnumberable<string> { "Strawberry", "Cherry" }
```